# Type inference with GADTs

Tags: haskell, ghc

In the following code, I'm trying to match on the GADT constructor `Cons` to get the compiler to see that `xs` is non-empty:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds           #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures      #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators       #-}

import Data.Typeable

data Foo (ts :: [*]) where
  Nil :: Foo '[]
  Cons :: (Typeable t) => Foo ts -> Foo ( t ': ts)

foo :: Foo xs -> IO ()
foo Nil = print "done"
foo (Cons rest :: Foo (y ': ys)) = do
  print $ show $ typeRep (Proxy::Proxy y)
  foo rest
```

Unfortunately, this simple example fails to compile with GHC 8:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘xs’ with ‘y : ys’
  ‘xs’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      foo :: forall (xs :: [*]). Foo xs -> IO ()
  Expected type: Foo (y : ys)
    Actual type: Foo xs
• When checking that the pattern signature: Foo (y : ys)
    fits the type of its context: Foo xs
  In the pattern: Cons rest :: Foo (y : ys)
  In an equation for ‘foo’:
      foo (Cons rest :: Foo (y : ys))
        = print $ (show $ typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy y))
```

I know that type inference can be tricky with GADTs (e.g., [#9695](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9695), [#10195](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10195), [#10338](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10338)), but this is *so* simple...

What do I need to do to convince GHC that when I match on `Cons`, the GADT argument has at least one element?

Comment: Why not simply have `foo :: Foo (x ': xs) -> ()`?

Comment: Of course this example is simplified, but `foo` really has some recursive calls in it. I need to match on either the `Cons` case or the `Nil` case (elided), and naturally `Nil :: Foo '[]`. I really do need GHC to figure out `xs ~ (y ': ys)` based on the pattern match.

Comment: @Alec I improved the example to demonstrate why I'm asking what I'm asking. I hate it when I oversimplify examples...

Comment: Thanks! As a side note, [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11350) would be really useful here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a function to extract the `Proxy t` from a `Foo (t ': ts)`:

```
fooFstType :: Foo (t ': ts) -> Proxy t 
fooFstType _ = Proxy
```

Note that since the type argument to `Foo` is `t ': ts`, not simply `ts`, you may refer to the type variable representing the first element in the type signature (as opposed to in the body, somehow, with `ScopedTypeVariables`).

Your function becomes

```
foo :: Foo xs -> IO ()
foo Nil = print "done"
foo f@(Cons rest) = do
  print $ show $ typeRep (fooFstType f)
  foo rest
```

Another possibility is to move the work to the type level:

```
type family First (xs :: [k]) :: k where 
  First (x ': xs) = x 

foo :: forall xs . Foo xs -> IO ()
foo Nil = print "done"
foo (Cons rest) = do
  print $ show $ typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy (First xs))
  foo rest
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this works, but it's more or less what I'm looking for. How silly that it requires a second function! Do you know if this behavior is documented somewhere?

Comment: If by 'behaviour' you are referring to why the error happens in the first place, it is a consequence of how typechecking works. The different given types (`Foo xs`, `Foo (y:ys)`) are matched before the function is actually typechecked, but of course we can only unify those under the context provided by the GADT pattern match. That pattern match simply hasn't 'happened' by the time the given types are unified. `ScopedTypeVariables` just isn't the right tool to solve this problem - we need [visible type applications in patterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11350).

Comment: SPJ confirmed that "that's just how it works" [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13430), which isn't very satisfactory, but seems to be the accepted solution. The double pattern match is so clunky though...